# Unable to Download ZIP File from jQuery-AJAX on Button Click event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My problem is: I am using a PHP script for zipping a folder and downloading it. But I am doing it by AJAX-jQuery code. So when I click on a button to generate a ZIP package, it won't work. But when I enabled IDM (Internet Download Manager), then it is downloaded. But after disabling the IDM ZIP file created but can not be downloaded. I have attached the AJAX response recorded on Chrome console.

This is my PHP function:

```
public function createZip($files, $zip_file_name) {
$valid_files = array();
    if(is_array($files)) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($valid_files > 0)){
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name = $zip_file_name.".zip";
        if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
            $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }

        foreach($valid_files as $file){
            $zip->addFile($file);
        }

        $zip->close();
        if(file_exists($zip_name)){
            // force to download the zip
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: private",false);
            header('Content-type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
            readfile($zip_name);
            // remove zip file from temp path
            unlink($zip_name);
           return "Files are successfully Archived !";
        }
        else{
            return "ERROR in ZIP FIle Archive!";
        }
    } else {
        return "No valid files to zip";
        exit;
    }
}
```

And this is my jQuery / AJAX code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.zip_dl', function(){
var click_id = $(this).attr('id');

//alert(click_id);

$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/AjaxResponses.php',
    data: {
        folder_name : click_id,
        action_type : "zip_file_download"
    },
    error: function() {
    //$('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {

    },
    type: 'GET'
});
});
```

Comment: It makes little sense to try and make a request that is supposed to result in the downloading of a file via AJAX. The result will only “land” in your JS code, and you would have to implement additional logic to pass it from there “to” the UI, so that the download dialog appears. Since you’re making a simple GET request, you can just use a normal link for that – and then you’ll have no problems with getting the DL dialog to appear, that will happen automatically in this case.